# Is there an easy way to show this matrix is totally unimodular?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Consider $2n\times n^2$ matrix
$$J=\begin{bmatrix}
C_{11}&C_{12}&\dots&C_{1n}\\
C_{21}&C_{22}&\dots&C_{2n}\\
\vdots\\
C_{n1}&C_{n2}&\dots&C_{nn}\\
D_{11}&D_{12}&\dots&D_{1n}\\
D_{21}&D_{22}&\dots&D_{2n}\\
\vdots\\
D_{n1}&D_{n2}&\dots&D_{nn}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

where each $C_{ij}$ and $D_{ij}$ is $1\times n$ submatrix.

$C_{ij}$ contains all $1$s iff $i=j$ else contains all $0$s.

$D$s form repetitions of $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Consider matrix of form $$\begin{bmatrix}J\\I_{n^2}\end{bmatrix}$$ where $I_{n^2}$ is identity of $n^2\times n^2$ size.

For example if $n=4$ we have
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1\\
1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

How does one show this type of matrix is always totally unimodular?